# imported function from another file is slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a function like this which loads fine if I am running it directly without importing it from another `helper.py` file.

I'm not sure what's causing the slow loading.

`helper_file.py`:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer 
def embed_answers(ans, length): 
    sentence_embeddings = []
    embeddings = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('...')
    sentence_embeddings.extend(embeddings.encode(ans, max_length=length, padding='max_length') 
    return sentence embeddings 

def get_dataset(vec_type): 
    vec_dict = {"large": 1000, "medium": 500, "small": 150} 
    if vec_type.lower() not in vec_dict: 
        raise Exception("Invalid vector type!")
    df = pd.read_hdf('...', mode='r')
    vec_length = vec_dict[vec_type]
    df['embeddings_col'] = df['answer'].apply(embed_answers, length=vec_length) 
    return df
```

When I import and call `get_dataset` from a `main.py` file it crashes without loading fully. But directly running the function from `main.py` is fine.

Not sure what's the issue, appreciate any ideas, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You've mentioned two issues.  1) Slow loading,  2) crashes when you call ```get_dataset()``` from main.py.   For 1), it's hard to know without the relevant details (actual minimal reproducible example).  for 2), please include the full traceback error (if that is what you mean by a crash), otherwise, if it just quits without doing anything,  that'll also need a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What's the error it gives you when it crashes?

Comment: Show the main.py and the import command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it can solve your problem but load the tokenizer each time you call `embed_answers` is a waste of resources (time and memory). Try to take advantage of vectorization.

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

def embed_answers(ans, length): 
    embeddings = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('...')
    inputs = embeddings(ans, max_length=length, padding='max_length') 
    return inputs['input_ids']

def get_dataset(vec_type): 
    vec_dict = {"large": 1000, "medium": 500, "small": 150} 
    if vec_type.lower() not in vec_dict: 
        raise Exception("Invalid vector type!")
    df = pd.read_hdf('...', mode='r')
    vec_length = vec_dict[vec_type]
    df['embeddings_col'] = embed_answers(df['answer'].tolist(), length=vec_length) 
    return df
```

Demo:

```
def embed_answers(ans, length): 
    embeddings = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
    inputs = embeddings(ans, max_length=length, padding='max_length') 
    return inputs['input_ids']

data = ["Hello, my dog is cute", "my cat is a daemon"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'answer': data})
df['embeddings_col'] = embed_answers(df['answer'].tolist(), length=10)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  answer                                        embeddings_col
0  Hello, my dog is cute  [101, 8667, 117, 1139, 3676, 1110, 10509, 102, 0, 0]
1     my cat is a daemon  [101, 1139, 5855, 1110, 170, 5358, 25027, 102, 0, 0]
```